# Can 2 9v batteries heat an electric range heating element

Tags: heat, battery-operated

For an experiment I am trying to power the heating element in the link attached.

http://www.appliancepartspros.com/frigidaire-range-surface-element-316442300-ap4356466.html

My goal is to power it with the most lightweight battery possible. If this isn't possible, are there lower voltage heating elements that 9v batteries in series can heat up?

Comment: You need to post the image in your question so that the question still makes sense when the link dies. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Which 9v batteries? Like in smoke detectors, or else?

Comment: A little looking at what exists in the world would show that compact non-reusable cooking power sources are examples of *combustion chemistry* not electrical storage.

Comment: It is like trying to run a farm tractor with an eyedropper of gasoline. If it could work, someone would have done it by now.

Comment: add k after 2 in title, then it's possible

Comment: Sure it'll heat it - but not very much, and not for very long. You may find it gets very slightly warm to the touch for a few minutes. But the batteries will probably get warmer.

Answer (score 2):

That is a 240V (or thereabouts) 2100W element, meaning it draws about 8.75A. You could conceivably use 65 or 70 16850 batteries in series, which would weigh about 3.5kg for the batteries alone. *Some* batteries allow discharge current in that range. Many do not allow it safely.

If you get 70% of, say, 2.5Ah then it might run for 10 or 15 minutes, enough to boil your tea and prepare some dehydrated food if it doesn't explode and take whatever structure it's in plus your face with it.

240VDC with so much current and charge capacity is also potentially lethal, more so even than 240VAC out of the wall.

---

As far as PP3 9V batteries, it would take quite a few of them in series-parallel to run that for any length of time and again, would be dangerous for shock at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Any heating element for a "electric range" requires way too much power for a few of those clip-on 9 V batteries to power.  You don't have to look at volts or amps.  Just look at the power required, and the total energy such a battery can deliver.

Getting even a small electric range heating element to meaningful cooking temperature takes 100s of watts.  Realistic ones take kW.

There is a reason that a electric range is always a 240 V appliance, even here in the US where things are 120 V to the extent possible.  The current required at 120 V would be so high, that it's better to go out of the way to use twice the voltage and therefore allow half the current.

Stop and actually *think* about it.  If 120 VAC that can deliver 10 A without much trouble isn't good enough for a range, then how do you imagine a 9 V battery that can barely deliver 1 A for short amounts of time is going to work out?

Let's be really generous and say that you have such a tiny heating element that it only needs 100 W.  Now compare that to the power a 9 V battery can put out.  To get 100 W from 9 V would require (100 W)/(9 V) = 11 A.  Not gonna happen.  Not even close.  And, 100 W is a joke for a range-top heating element.

Comment: Maybe the OP has different batteries, like this one, or even bigger :-) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/152470/117785

Comment: @Ali: Maybe, but he hasn't said.  That's why I was careful to qualify what kind of 9 V batteries I was answering about.

Answer (score 0):

THis is incredibly naive.

Stove element specs: e.g. 120V 12A means 1440 Watts, 10 Ohms.

So this means a battery must have a V*Ah capacity of  at least 1.4kW for 1 hour capacity.

- meanwhile a good car battery of say 50Ah and 12 V is 600 Wh and you want to heat 1.4kW with a 9V battery? nice try. How old are you?

Comment: But a stove burner makes a passable dummy load for 160 meters.